# Linux says a kernel module has an unknown symbol, but another loaded module provides it

Tags: linux, dependencies, kernel-modules

I'm trying to install [a driver for a USB DAQ box](http://support.advantech.com.tw/support/DownloadSRDetail.aspx?SR_ID=1-41GHVV&Doc_Source=Download), which annoyingly, I have to compile myself. I believe I've succeeded -- I have two .ko files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  45271 2010-03-18 21:24 advdrv_core.ko
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  24312 2010-03-18 21:24 usb4761.ko
```

I was able to run insmod on the first without incident, but when I try on the second, I get a flood of messages:

```
kernel: [686782.106547] usb4761: no symbol version for adv_process_info_check_event
kernel: [686782.106555] usb4761: Unknown symbol adv_process_info_check_event
kernel: [686782.106691] usb4761: no symbol version for advdrv_unregister_driver
kernel: [686782.106695] usb4761: Unknown symbol advdrv_unregister_driver
```

However, advdrv_core.ko provides these symbols. My kernel sure seems to have them in memory:

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep advdrv_unregister_driver
f8d88504 r __ksymtab_advdrv_unregister_driver   [advdrv_core]
f8d888d2 r __kstrtab_advdrv_unregister_driver   [advdrv_core]
f8d885a4 r __kcrctab_advdrv_unregister_driver   [advdrv_core]
086eb8fb a __crc_advdrv_unregister_driver       [advdrv_core]
f8d86e90 t advdrv_unregister_driver     [advdrv_core]
```

Why does my insmod claim they're unknown symbols?

Edit: One of the answers below advised me to copy the files to /lib/modules and run depmod. So I did, using depmod's -v (verbose) option. Among the output were a bunch of lines like:

```
/lib/modules/2.6.27-7-generic/kernel/drivers/pcmcia/usb4761.ko needs "advdrv_unregister_driver": /lib/modules/2.6.27-7-generic/kernel/drivers/pcmcia/advdrv_core.ko
```

Then I ran rmmod advdrv_core to make sure I was installing it fresh, ran modprobe advdrv_core, and finally ran modprobe usb4761.

Again, a bunch of failed symbols, including advdrv_unregister_driver.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718358/insmod-unknown-symbol-in-module

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issues compiling Advantech drivers. The operative phrase here is really "no symbol version".

Section 7 of http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.33/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt provides details on module versioning. Section 7.3 is of particular interest. The simplest solution for me was just to stick in a `KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS` line (as described starting at [line 526](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.33/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt#L526) of modules.txt above). In your case, you could probably just add a line like

```
KBUILD_EXTRA_SYMBOLS := <driver_root>/kernel/core/Module.symvers
```

to the top of `<driver_root>/kernel/USB-4761/Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

copy the .ko's to your kernel's module directory then run `depmod`